# How do you use the sorting function in OpenFDA for registration listing?

Tags: api, medical, openfda, uses-of-open-data, healthcare-finder-api

Can you sort "sort=receivedate:desc&limit=10" under the registration listing for product.created_date?

Answer (score 0):

The Device Registration & Listings endpoint does not have that particular field: *receivedate*.

For a complete list of available fields, please refer to https://open.fda.gov/apis/device/registrationlisting/searchable-fields/

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am still receiving error when using these parameters. Please assist with the correction for sorting dates.      https://api.fda.gov/device/registrationlisting.json?search=products.created_date&sort=asc&limit=1

Comment: Sure, here you go: https://api.fda.gov/device/registrationlisting.json?sort=products.created_date:asc&limit=1

Comment: Great! Your help has been appreciated.